# Is "region " is any keyword in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, region

Is "region" a keyword in asp.net?  If yes, then what does it mean and where would one use it?

Comment: Is region a keyword? In C# it's used like `#regionx xxx` to create a collapsible code block, but has no bearing on how the program behaves.

Comment: You should realy try to except some of the answers given to your questions. Its the right thing to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#region Description
//here is your code.

#endregion
```

Answer (score 5):

What do you mean keyword? ASP.NET is not a programming language.

If you're asking about C#, then no, `region` isn't a keyword. `#region` is something like a keyword, though.

Comment: It is a preprocessor directive *(Not worth posting a separate answer as you have covered the key points.)*

Comment: Also people should really start learning to use the tools giving to them before they hobble together a website...

Comment: It is a *compilator* directive (C# doesn't have a preprocessor)

Comment: @wRAR - MSDN doesn't lie *(Well I hope so.)*. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx

Comment: Sorry,I am asking about #region in C#.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: Ah, sorry :) Btw, they are called *pre-processing directives* in ECMA-334.

Comment: @Chaos: can you please fix that link to remove the version number?

Answer (score 1):

Region is not keyword in asp.net but#region is keyword for organize your code see the link

About #Region - ASP.NET Forums

http://forums.asp.net/p/1142786/1842461.aspx